# What is the $\lim_{n\to \infty} {\sqrt[n]{(1+1/n)(1+2/n)...(1+n/n)}}$

Tags: calculus, limits, radicals

Because $(1+\frac{k}{n})\leq (1+\frac{1}{n})^k$ $$ {\sqrt[n]{(1+1/n)(1+2/n)...(1+n/n)}}\leq\sqrt[n]{(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n(n+1)/2}}=(1+\frac{1}{n})^{(n+1)/2}$$ and so $$\lim_{n\to \infty}{\sqrt[n]{(1+1/n)(1+2/n)...(1+n/n)}}<\sqrt{e}$$

But what is the exact limit?

> Added: I Gave this to [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Clim_%7Bn%5Cto+%5Cinfty%7D+%5Csqrt%5Bn%5D%7B(1%2B1%2Fn)*(1%2B2%2Fn)*...*(1%2Bn%2Fn)%7D) and the answer was $\infty$ ! but why?[image: ![enter image description here]
>   [image]

Comment: It depends on how Wolfram interprets $\dots$

Comment: Try the correct Mathematica notation [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Limit%5BProduct%5B(1%2Bk%2Fn)%5E(1%2Fn),%7Bk,1,n%7D%5D,n-%3EInfinity%5D), it gives the correct value of the limit

Comment: @YuriyS Thanks. What is the interpretation of ... for Wolfram in this case?

Comment: I don't know. I always use Mathematica language

Comment: Minor remark:  AGM gives a better bound than $\sqrt e$:  $$\sqrt[n]{(1+1/n)(1+2/n)...(1+n/n)}\le{1\over n}\left(n+{1+2+\cdots+n\over n}\right)\to{3\over2}$$

Comment: @BarryCipra It's beautiful!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take logarithm:

$$\frac1n \sum_{k=1}^n \log \left( 1 + \frac{k}n\right)$$

which converges (using Riemann sums) to:

$$\int_0^1 \log(1+x) dx = 2\log 2 - 1$$

Therefore the original limit is:

$$e^{2 \log 2 -1} = 4/e$$

Comment: Oh yes! that's fine!

Answer (score 2):

You can apply Cauchy's limit theorem

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{a_n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n},$$

with

$$a_n = (1+1/n)(1+2/n)…(1+n/n) = \frac{(2n)!}{n! n^n}.$$

Then

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac{(2n+2)!}{(n+1)!(n+1)^{n+1}}\frac{n!n^n}{(2n)!} \\ = \frac{(2n+2)(2n+1)n^n}{(n+1)(n+1)^{n+1}} \\ = 2\frac{(2 + 1/n)}{(1+1/n)}\frac{1}{(1+1/n)^n},$$

and

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = 2 \cdot 2 \cdot \frac{1}{e} = \frac{4}{e}$$

Comment: This is a great idea. Thanks.